# Performance static initialisation

Tags: java, static

which one is the best way to access static elements? Lets say that I have a class which will serve to share an static array of int.

**option A**

```
final class A {
static private int[] a;
static {
    a = new int[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = i*50;
    }
}
static int getA(int index) {
    int tmp = a[index];
    return tmp;
}
```

} 
**option B**

```
final class B {
static private int[] b;
static int getB(int index) {
    b = new int[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length;i++) {
        b[i] = i*50;
    }
    int tmp = b[index];
    return tmp;
}
```

}
**Access**

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numA = A.getA(50);
    System.out.println(numA);
    int numB = B.getB(50);
    System.out.println(numB);
}
```

}

Which one is the best in term of performance. Or is exactly the same thing;
thank in advance

Comment: The computation in the `static` block of the first example will occur once, whereas in the second example, it will occur for each call of the method.

Comment: Both poor. Have you considered `retrurn index*50;`?

Comment: well this is just a simple example to keep it simple. I just want to know in term of perfomance. if I use non regular values your suggestion won't work. thank you anyway

Comment: @Litiec it is hopefully obvious that doing something every time is slower for multiple calls than doing it once and reusing the result. So what performance are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious difference between the `A` and `B` classes is that in the case of the latter, the `int[]` array would be initialized every time the getter is called.  In the absence of further requirements, this seems unnecessary.  So, I vote for using the `A` class implementation.

Comment: Thank that's was i though but I wasn't sure. So in case we need share to arrays of any type between classes the A option is the best. thank you

Comment: If the example you gave is a proxy for something else, and you want to add more information to your question, then I'm happy to update.

Comment: I just want to confirm because I wasn't not sure. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is better than `B`. In `B`, each time the `getB` function is called, a new `int[]` is created, which will cost both time and memory space in heap. Also the for loop in `getB` may be executed multiple times.